# Incompatible types with LiveData of a child as a LiveData of a parent

Tags: android, android-studio, android-livedata

I want to use MutableLiveData to observe some data from a ViewModel. The problem is that I use child and parent class, and there is some incompatibility with LiveData.
An example of what I want to do in Kotlin:

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel

class Test : ViewModel() {

    abstract class Parent(protected var id: Int)

    class ChildFirst(id: Int) : Parent(id)

    class ChildSecond(id: Int) : Parent(id)

    var childFirst : MutableLiveData<ChildFirst> = MutableLiveData<ChildFirst>()

    var childSecond : MutableLiveData<ChildSecond> = MutableLiveData<ChildSecond>()

    var shouldManageFirstChild = true

    fun returnCorrectChild(): MutableLiveData<Parent> {
        if (shouldManageFirstChild) {
            return childFirst //won't compile in Android Studio (Type mismatch)
        } else {
            return childSecond as MutableLiveData<Parent> //compile and work with a warning in AndroidStudio (Unchecked cast)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is in Java :

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class Test extends ViewModel {
    class Parent {
        protected int mId;

        Parent(int id) {
            mId = id;
        }
    }

    class ChildFirst extends Parent {
        ChildFirst(int id) {
            super(id);
        }
    }

    class ChildSecond extends Parent {
        ChildSecond(int id) {
            super(id);
        }
    }

    MutableLiveData<ChildFirst> childFirst = new MutableLiveData <ChildFirst>();

    MutableLiveData<ChildSecond> childSecond = new MutableLiveData <ChildSecond>();
    boolean shouldManageFirstChild = true;

    MutableLiveData<Parent> returnCorrectChild(){
        if (shouldManageFirstChild) {
            return childFirst; //won't compile in Android Studio (Incompatible type)
        } else {
            return (MutableLiveData<Parent>) childSecond;   //won't compile in Android Studio (Inconvertible cast)
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, the problem is that the compiler don't consider the type the same for MutableLiveData<Child> and MutableLiveData<Parent>.

In Kotlin, I can cast the LiveData of a child as a parent. Even if there is a warning, the code run as intended: I can observe a MutableLiveData<Parent>.

Worse, in Java, it's impossible to compile, even with a cast.

So here is my question:

- Why I can't use the LiveData of a child as the LiveData of a parent ? Is that something intended by the LiveData ?
- Are they some eventual consequences of casting it with the kotlin 'as' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why I can't use the LiveData of a child as the LiveData of a parent ?
>   Is that something intended by the LiveData ?

In java the answer is quite simple: generic types in Java are invariant, meaning that `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>` (quoted from kotlin docs [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance))

> Are they some eventual consequences of casting it with the kotlin 'as'
>   ?

Kotlin is simply doing a compile time warning, but what happens in runtime is that your check is only agains the non generics part. That's why, I think (and if anyone know better than me, please explain! I'm courios about this), you can do it in Kotlin.

For a better explanation of what happens in kotlin (and also in Java) while using the generics type i recommend you to read the the full kotlin docs about generics [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html)
There is even plenty of articles about java generics casting like [this](http://www.javarticles.com/2014/12/type-casting.html) one

**EDIT:**
A way for resolving your problem could be this:
declare a single live data and treat the childs in a simple manner like this:

```kotlin
val liveParent = MutableLiveData<Parent>()
val childFirst = ChildFirst()
val childSecond = ChildSecond()
```

and then return the correct child in the `liveParent` while calling `returnCorrectChild()`

```js
fun returnCorrectChild() {
    if (shouldManageFirstChild) {
        liveParent.value = firstChild
    } else {
        liveParent.value = secondChild
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and thanks for the example of a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your returnCorrectChild() function to return a generic type and then check if the returned type is an instance of ChildFirst or ChildSecond outside your ViewModel class

Something like:

```
  fun returnCorrectChild(): MutableLiveData<*> {
        if (shouldManageFirstChild) {
            return childFirst
        } else {
            return childSecond
        }
    }
```

Outside your viewModel class:

```kotlin
yourLiveDataInstance.observe(this@YourActivity, Observer {
            when(it){
                is ChildFirst -> {
                    // do stuff for ChildFirst
                }
                is ChildSecond ->{
                    // do stuff for ChildSecond
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Problem with that solution: I just want to use the Parent in the observer, and that just add a cast when I shouldn't need one (in theory)
And you really answer my question.